Applicability of W.S. Andrews' 'Magic Cubes and Squares' for Modern Combinatorics Course
I'm currently enrolled in a combinatorics course and am considering using 'Magic Cubes and Squares' by W.S. Andrews as a supplementary resource. Given that the book is quite old, I would like to know if it still provides relevant and accurate information for current studies in combinatorics. Could anyone familiar with this book share their insights on its applicability to modern mathematical puzzles and combinatorics education?
